# What exactly is echo '[local]\nlocalhost\n' > /etc?

Tags: linux, shell, docker

```
RUN echo '[local]\nlocalhost\n' > /etc/ansible/hosts
```

This line is in my dockerfile, and I assume it just means add localhost to the ansible/hosts file?

Can someone break down what [local]\nlocalhost\n is in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line tells Docker to run the shell command: `echo '[local]\nlocalhost\n' > /etc/ansible/hosts`

That shell command will print the following text block in the file `/etc/ansible/hosts`:

```
[local]
localhost
```

It does this because `\n` is the "newline" character, signaling the beginning of a new text line. That means that `echo` has been instructed to do the following: print the text `[local]`, then start a new line, print `localhost`, and finally start another new line. This output is redirected using the special `>` character, and the destination after redirection is specified as `/etc/ansible/hosts`. While that file may not have a `.txt` extension, you can think of it as a plain text file.

That file is probably specified  because it is used by Ansible to communicate with different hosts (in this case localhost) through its [inventory functionality](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html).

So yes, you were essentially correct -- this adds localhost to the Ansible hosts file. It's worth noting that this command will overwrite any existing file at `/etc/ansible/hosts`.

Answer (score 1):

The line in question:

```
RUN echo '[local]\nlocalhost\n' > /etc/ansible/hosts
```

appears to run the `echo` command and use the shell redirect character `>` to send the output of the `echo` command into the file `/etc/ansible/hosts`.

Two things to note here:

- In the `echo` command, the `\n` sequence stands for a newline character (<kbd>Enter</kbd> key). So `[local]` and `localhost` are actually being echoed to the file on consecutive lines. This corresponds to the proper format for a stanza in `/etc/ansible/hosts` as described [here](http://devopscube.com/install-configure-ansible-server-nodes/). (I don't know enough about ansible to tell you why the hostname `localhost` is used here instead of the IP address `127.0.0.1`.)
- The shell redirect character `>` will *overwrite* (that is, it will erase and replace) the contents of `/etc/ansible/hosts` rather than *appending* this new stanza to the end of the file. (To redirect and append to a file, you would use `>>` instead.)